# how to keep unknown variables that passed by my class user

Tags: c++, variables

I need a kind of variable in c++ to save all objects and ... like "Object" in c# anyway I want to pass every kind of vars in it . (unknown variables )

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `boost::any` and `boost::variant` from the Boost library.

That said, usually a need to circumvent the type system is an indication of something wrong. Instead of using one of the aforementioned solutions, I recommend thinking hard about what constraints put you in this direction.